# Selectively replacing icons in an icon pack theme?

Tags: elementary-os, icons, panel

I'm currently running elementary OS and just love the style and size of the panel icons (WiFi, Bluetooth, power, battery). I installed the Numix circle icon pack and activated it using Elementary tweaks and that ofcourse, replaced the panel icons as well. To me, the panel icons look ugly because they are out of proportion.

Elementary default icons:

[image]

Panel icons with the numix icon pack:

[image]

Is there a way I could customize this so that all the other icons are based on Numix icons but the panel icons are the same as those elementary uses by default? Or be able to shrink the icon size in the panel?

Comment: The icons size in the panel is the same, the actual symbols are different sizes... As to changing the icons: you either copy the Elementary panel icons over the numix ones in _/usr/share/icons..._ or remove the panel icons from numix and edit its `index.theme` to _inherit_ Elementary.

Comment: Yea, @don_crissti, that should work. Why don't you post it as an answer?

Comment: Thanks @don_crissti, I did manage to tweak the index.theme (simply copying icons did not work) to use elementary icons for the panel instead of numix. I got it to work partly, but I now get the idea!

Comment: Yeah, the problem is that you can only use one theme at a time so using _inherits_ is the best solution. Also, keep in mind that icon themes in `/usr/share/icons` might be overwritten by future upgrades so place your custom theme in `~/.local/share/icons` (you can even give it a different name).

Comment: aaah I see. How can I create a custom theme though? I mean just giving the folder a name and a structure similar to the base theme I'm trying to emulate should be enough?

Comment: Please prepend your comments with `@don_crissti` otherwise I won't be notified... Yeah, to create a custom theme you just copy the original them from `/usr/share/icons` to `~/.local/share/icons`, rename the theme folder e.g. `~./local/share/icons/darthnumix`and use the same name in the `index.theme` e.g. `name=darthnumix` and then `Inherits=elementary`etc... the hardest part is identifying the icons used in the panel (so that you can remove them). Here are the icon [names used in gnome](https://github.com/GNOME/gnome-icon-theme-symbolic/tree/master/gnome/scalable/status) if it helps...

Comment: And don't forget to rebuild the icon cache once you're done removing icons: `gtk-update-icon-cache -f ~./local/share/icons/darthnumix` otherwise your theme will use the old cache...